# Python social auth - AuthStateForbidden: Wrong state parameter given, while adding Instagram account

Tags: oauth, instagram, python-social-auth

When I'm already logged in on Instagram and try to add Instagram account to my app then it works just fine. But, when I'm not logged in on Instagram and try to add it to my app then it fails with 500 server error with the **exception AuthStateForbidden: Wrong state parameter given.**

**The same works fine for Twitter, Facebook, and LinkedIn for both the cases (already logged in and not logged in).**

I've tried all solutions suggested here, but nothing seems to work for me.

I understand the exception is because the state sent and received and not same! Below are the sent and received state values.

**state:** hhlonbffpevl8kjirdppbc6v6zmalhcy

**redirect_state:** HHlONBFfpevl8kjIRDPPBc6v6ZMALhCY

As you can see it's just the case issue! Why is this even happening? How do I resolve this? Please help!

Comment: I found a solution! I know it's not full proof but I had no other go. I had to edit social auth library file (oauth.py) and changed state and redirect_state equality check to case insensitive check. That works fine for now.

Comment: You can look on this ticket https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/534#issuecomment-407466324 There are a few possible solutions been suggested to fix it.